# Как обрабатывать динамические url в Angular?

Tags: javascript, url, angularjs

Есть адреса вида `example.com/2015/04/20/`,  `example.com/2015/04/`,  `example.com/2015/` Как обрабатывать такие адреса в роутах? Т.е. необходимо что-то вроде `(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/?', DaysHandler)` (как это делается в python фреймворках)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если для роутинга используете angular-ui-router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router , то так - в `$stateProvider`:

```
.state('something', {
                url: '/something/:year/:month/:day'
```

В контроллере вьюхи инжектим `$stateParams`, в котором параметры будут доступны по их именам.